# Apache-jena-fuseki running on Ubuntu 19.10 password?

Tags: jena

I am following this tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/nichtich/113ecc2831d01eb4ae91508b88c0217c
in order to install Apche-jena-fuseki on Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop. The version I am using is: apache-jena-fuseki-3.14.0

When I execute this command:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/fuseki
```

I give password: `pw` 
as I found from google search but it does not accept it....
Which is the deafault password for this version? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If "sudo vim" asks for a password, it is sudo asking for the local system root password. This is not Fuseki asking.